# who is sending orientation changed event in android

Tags: android

I observed one problem in status bar that while we open it from the home screen and change the device to landscape mode, the orientation of the status bar is not changed to landscape,
but if we open any applications like messaging in which their orientation is changed according to device orientation and then open the status bar, it will also change the orientation.

That means keeping an application who orientation is constant in background and then opening the status bar will have this problem that orientation of status bar also becomes constant.

Please give me some suggestions so that I can rectify this problem. If I could know that who is parsing the xml file and if android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" is present in the manifest file who is deciding not to send Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED

Answer (score 0):

you should prepaire to create landscape layout also.

for landscape mode-> layout-land
for portrait mode-> layout

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"   , this tag used when we dont want to change state in our activity when  orientation is changed

Comment: Thank for your replies. My concern here is the notification bar(status bar) is not getting rotated according to the device orientation,if any apps that have the the default orientation (for eg the apps that use android:screenOrientation="portrait") is in the background.

Sorry I mean android:screenOrientation="portrait" in my question instead of android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation.

Comment: if you are given android:screenOrientation="portrait" ,  so device rotate but your screen does not rotated..

Comment: and also if u use android:screenOrientation="landscape" ,,same its work only for landscape mode .

Comment: if u r not giving a proper response so no one take intrest to giveing answer of your query.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. I know that  android:screenOrientation="portrait" ,the screen wont rotate, but i am intrested to know why this is happening and who is deciding this, because of the status bar problem I mentioned in my question. It is a framework code , you can see this in platoform/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI

Answer (score 0):

if android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" is present in the manifest file then our activity will handle itself  one or more configuration changes that we specify and need not to handle by android system.
That means when we use android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" we tell android system that our activity itself controll this configuration change.